How to Handle Errors Globally in a React App Without Crashing the Entire Application
I'm building a React application and want to implement global error handling that only affects the specific component where the error occurs, without crashing the entire app.
Currently, I use an ErrorBoundary component at the top level, but it causes the entire application to display the fallback UI if any child component throws an error. I want a solution that targets only the component with the error, allowing the rest of the app to continue running smoothly.
Additionally, I do not want to wrap each component individually with an error boundary. Here's what I have so far:
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    console.error("Error caught by ErrorBoundary: ", error, errorInfo);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;

With this setup, if any child component throws an error, the entire app shows the fallback UI. How can I handle errors so that only the errored component is affected, keeping the rest of the app running? Is there a way to do this with a single import or setup at the top level?
